# Pandas TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some data-discovery using Python/Pandas.

MVCE: I have a CSV file with some street addresses and I want to find the length of the longest address in my file. (this is a simplified version of my actual problem)

I wrote this simple Python code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])

print(df['address'].map(len).max())
```

The address column is of type str, or so I thought (see below).

Why then do I get this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eval-lengths.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(df['address'].map(len).max())
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2996, in map
    arg, na_action=na_action)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 1004, in _map_values
    new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Here's the output of `df.info()`

```
RangeIndex: 154733 entries, 0 to 154732
Data columns (total 2 columns):
address    154510 non-null object
zip        154732 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 2.4+ MB
```

*UPDATE*

Here's a sample CSV file

```
address,zip
555 APPLE STREET,82101
1180 BANANA LAKE ROAD,81913
577 LEMON DR,81911
,99999
```

The last line is key to reproducing the problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug on a shortened csv file and provide the csv file?  It's hard to debug without that.  Also, maybe provide output of `df.dtypes` and `df['address'][:5]` so we can see that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have missing data in your column, represented by NaNs (which are of float type).

Don't use `map`/`apply`, etc for things like finding the length, just do this with `str.len`:

```
df['address'].str.len()
```

Items for which `len()` is not applicable automatically show in the result as NaN. You can `fillna(-1)` those out to indicate the result is invalid there.

Comment: You are correct, the empty string ("") is apparently converted to a float. This is totally counter-intuitive for someone coming to Python from other programming languages. In most other languages, an empty string is still a string. Changing `map(len)` to `str.len()` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 8):

My Solution was to fillNa with an empty string and then try to run the apply, like this:

```
df['address'].fillna('', inplace=True)
print(df['address'].map(len).max())
```